# Dataframe within Dataframe to retrieve Stock Information

Tags: r

So I have a dataframe with Stock Symbols, Ratings, Company names, and etc. What I wanted to do was to add a new column called extra information where I could have a dataframe within a dataframe.

I know I can use the code below to get a dataframe of specific information for a company:

```
data <- getSymbols("TSLA", src = 'yahoo', from = as.Date(Sys.time())-7, 
                  auto.assign=FALSE, verbose=TRUE)
```

However, I would like to get this stock information for every company when I click it's value on the Extra Information column. Any ideas?

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: The Quantmod package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can store the data in a list.

```
library(quantmod)
stock <- c("TSLA", 'QQQ')

result <- sapply(stock, getSymbols, src = 'yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE, 
                 from = as.Date(Sys.time())-7, verbose=TRUE, simplify = FALSE)
```

Now you can access individual stocks with `$` symbol.

```
result$TSLA
#           TSLA.Open TSLA.High TSLA.Low TSLA.Close TSLA.Volume TSLA.Adjusted
#2021-02-01    814.29    842.00   795.56     839.81    25391400        839.81
#2021-02-02    844.68    880.50   842.20     872.79    24346200        872.79
#2021-02-03    877.02    878.08   853.06     854.69    18343500        854.69
#2021-02-04    855.00    856.50   833.42     849.99    15812700        849.99
#2021-02-05    855.00    864.77   839.00     852.23    18566637        852.23
```

When you View the `result` object you get the stock symbols with their names.

[image]